# Variable expansion did not happen in /etc/environment

Tags: linux-mint, environment-variables

I changed the `/etc/environment` to add more directories to the `PATH` variable. But looks like `$PATH` in double quotes were not expanded and I could find any command from the shell and `/usr/bin/command-not-found` is run.

```
$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
PATH="$PATH:/home/user/technical/java/maven/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/home/user/technical/java/jdk7"
```

so from the tty,

```
$ echo $PATH
$PATH:/home/user/technical/java/maven/bin
```

why did not the expansion happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/etc/environment is shell agnostic.
This means it doesn't depend on the way e.g. bash to any *expansion*.

You can use only the simple `key=value` assignments here.

Comment: which process reads these key pairs?

Comment: e.g. look at `grep "/etc/environment" /etc/pam.d/*`

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/environment` file comes from the [Linux-PAM project](http://www.linux-pam.org) and is not a shell script. Since neither a shell nor PAM perform variable expansions on this file, the variables' values will be assigned as they are written in the file.

The `/etc/environment` file [is documented](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html) by the project:

> The `/etc/environment` file specifies the environment variables to be set. The file must consist of simple `NAME=VALUE` pairs on separate lines. The `pam_env(8)` module will read the file after the `pam_env.conf` file.

The `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` file is also not a shell script, but it *does* support a way of referring to other variables using the `${variable}` syntax. It also supports the two special expressions `@{HOME}` and `@{SHELL}` and will replace these with the appropriate values read from the user's `passwd` entry.

Note that the syntax for defining a variable in this file is different from in a shell script:

```
VARIABLE [DEFAULT=[value]] [OVERRIDE=[value]]
```

See the documentation at the link above for more information.